# how to access field models which on admin.TabularInline

Tags: python, django

I'm new on django, and I want to build an application called "Recycle Bank".

Here's my models.py

```
class Waste(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    wtype = models.ForeignKey(WasteType)
    specification = models.TextField(blank=True)
    purchasing_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Purchasing(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    officer = models.ForeignKey(Officer)
    waste = models.ManyToManyField(Waste, through='PurchasingDetail')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.user.username

class PurchasingDetail(models.Model):
    waste = models.ForeignKey(Waste)
    purchasing = models.ForeignKey(Purchasing)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Here's my admin.py

```
class PurchasingDetailInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PurchasingDetail
    extra = 1

class PurchasingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['client', 'timestamp', 'officer',]
    fields = ('client',)
    inlines = [PurchasingDetailInlineAdmin,]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.officer_id = request.user.id
        obj.save()
```

So, I want to set the `price` object in `PurchasingDetail(models.Model)` with specified counting (in this case: `Waste.purchasing_price` * `PurchasingDetail.weight`). I know I have to get access to `PurchasingDetail(models.Model)` object like I do on my `save_model()`. How to do this?

Here's my admin interface screenshots https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2dFcp9QmLL2X2duVHVfeVNHNlU

Thank you.

Comment: If price is always computed, you can use a property instead of a field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-methods